Calculate quarter gap between each purchase
I have a table with MemberNo as Row, Year and Quarter as Column, Purchase as Value. I'm trying to calculate the total average time gap of purchase of list of members.

In this example case, Member 10521321 has a time gap of 4 quarters.
Member 113213213 has 4 quarters, 5 quarters, and 3 quarters, thus the average gap for the member is 4 quarters (12/3). Ultimately, I wish to find the total average gap of all members.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Also this looks like a pivot table, which is the result from data. Do you want to use the pivot table as data, or your actual data? What was your own approach and where did it strand?

By total average do you mean the average of all the averages? Ignoring the first (blank) case, if you averaged over members you would get (9+4+4)/3=5.67, or if you averaged over gaps you would get (9+4+4+5+3)/5 = 5.0 so there would be a difference. If there were zero or one purchase for a member, would you want to omit it?

This formula uses the COLUMN and LARGE functions to calculate the distances between the non-empty cells.
In cell Q1 and drag down
=LET(col,IF(ISBLANK(B1:O1),0,COLUMN(B1:O1)),
count,SUM(IF(col<>0,1,0)),
dist,LARGE(col,SEQUENCE(1,count-1,1))-LARGE(col,SEQUENCE(1,count-1,2)),
SUM(dist)/COUNT(dist))



To average it over rows we could use the fact that the average gap length in a row is just the gap between the first and last '1' divided by the number of gaps so we could try:
=LET(range,B3:Q8,
gap,BYROW(range,LAMBDA(r,MAX(IF(r=1,COLUMN(r)))-MIN(IF(r=1,COLUMN(r))))),
count,BYROW(range,LAMBDA(r,COUNT(r))),
div,IFERROR(gap/(count-1),0),
SUM(div)/SUM(--(div>0)))

On the other hand, if we wanted to average it over  gaps rather than rows we could use Frequency:
=LET(range,B3:Q8,
gaps,REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(ROWS(range)),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,IFERROR(DROP(DROP(FREQUENCY(IF(INDEX(range,c,0)<>1,COLUMN(range)),IF(INDEX(range,c,0)=1,COLUMN(range)))+1,1),-1),0)))),
SUM(gaps)/SUM(--(gaps>0)))


